# react-native webview doesn't appear

Tags: react-native, webview

For some reason, my react-native webview doesn't show up at all.  Nothing shows up after my text field.  Here's my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


import {
View,
Text,
WebView,

} from 'react-native';


export default class Home extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
        <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
          <Text>Show webview</Text>
          <WebView source={{html:"<html><body style='color:red'>Hello<br/>This is a test</body></html>"}} style={{width:200,height:200,backgroundColor:'blue',marginTop:20}} />
        </View>
        );
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add `flex: 1` to your `<View />` component.

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection:'column'}}>
  <Text>Show webview</Text>
  <WebView source={{html:"<html><body style='color:red'>Hello<br/>This is a test</body></html>"}} style={{width:200,height:200,backgroundColor:'blue',marginTop:20}} />
</View>
```

[Here's a demo](https://snack.expo.io/SyQzp07RW)

Comment: I'm still new to flex, can you tell me why it has to be applied to View?  I thought if anything, it should be applied to the Text and WebView.

Comment: You've probably figured this out, but to answer the question, flex: 1 means to fill the remaining space that is left from the parent. Without it, or without a "height" it had no instruction to display itself other than a height of 0.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ReactNative docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview) as of (Nov 2019) they say this:

`Warning Please use the`[react-native-community/react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview)`fork of this component instead. To reduce the surface area of React Native, <WebView/> is going to be removed from the React Native core. For more information, please read The Slimmening proposal.`

I wasn't able to get the ReactNative `<WebView/>` to work at all in my Expo app. So switching to the react-native-community/react-native-webview `<WebView/>` component worked for me. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default AppWebview = () => (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/MhkGQAoc7bc'}}
          style={styles.video}
        />
        <WebView
          source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/PGUMRVowdv8'}}
          style={styles.video}
        />
      </View>
    );
 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',

  },
  video: {
    marginTop: 20,
    maxHeight: 200,
    width: 320,
    flex: 1
  }
});
```